# Is every connected complete Riemannian manifold of non-positive sectional curvature a Polish space?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Question: is it true that every finite-dimensional connected complete Riemannian manifold of non-positive sectional curvature is a Polish space, i.e. homeomorphic to a complete separable metric space?

My reasoning is that by the [Cartan-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem), a universal covering space of a connected complete Riemannian manifold of non-positive sectional curvature is diffeomorphic, and thus also homeomorphic, to a Euclidean space. The space itself is a universal covering space by taking the identity map as a universal cover, and the Euclidean space is a complete separable metric space.

Comment: The space itself need not be a universal cover (think of $S^ 1$). However, complete Riemannian manifolds are always complete separable metric spaces.

Comment: Whitney's theorem shows  that *any* connected  smooth manifold  $M$ can be  *properly* imbedded in an Euclidean  space $E$. In other words you can view $M$ as  a *closed* subset of an Euclidean space with the induced topology. As such it is a Polish space.  For details on Whitney's  imbedding see Chapter IV Sect 1 of Whitney's *Geometric Integration Theory*.

Comment: I have to amend my comment with another.  Whitney's definition of manifold includes the assumption that it admits a countable atlas.

Comment: In the context of the question asked: Riemannian implies metrizable implies paracompact + connected implies second countable and so the countable atlas assumption is not an obstruction.

Comment: It may be a question of definitions.  Some people might consider an uncountable disjoint union of, say, circles, to be a smooth manifold, since it's locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^1$, and then you could equip it with a Riemannian metric.  This isn't Polish because it's not separable.  In that context, the long line might also be a Riemannian manifold.  But most people impose a second-countability assumption, in which case it's true that every second-countable smooth manifold is Polish.

Comment: For me the easiest way to get there is that any locally compact, Hausdorff, second countable space $X$ is Polish.  (The one-point compactification $X^*$ is compact Hausdorff and second countable, hence metrizable by Urysohn.  So $X$ is an open subset of a compact metric space, hence is completely metrizable with a different compatible metric.)